# How would I add a listview fragment to this code?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

How would I add a custom list view fragment into this code so it is displayed under one of the tabs on the view pager?

I am trying to get it so it also displays a picture, I have a proper xml file with the list view layout but am having troubles trying to get it into one of the tabbed fragments.

Here is my code.

> MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private List<Posts> myPosts = new ArrayList<Posts>();
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        populatePostList();
        populateListView();
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    private void populatePostList()     {
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));
        myPosts.add(new Posts("Ottawa, Ontario", "787", "Picture of my Dog!", R.drawable.dog));



    }

    private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<Posts> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Posts> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, myPosts);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Make sure we have a view to work with {may have given null}
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            }
            // Find the post to work with.
            Posts currentPost = myPosts.get(position);


            //Fill the view
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_postImage);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentPost.getIconID());

            //Fill in Title

            TextView titleText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_postText);
            //titleText.setText(currentPost.getPosttitle());

            //Set Vote Number
            TextView voteText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_postVoteText);
            voteText.setText(currentPost.getPostvote());


            return itemView;
        }
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new TheWallFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new TheWallFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new TheWallFragment();
                default:
                    break;

            }
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

> fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> TheWallFragment

```
public class TheWallFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.wall_layout, container, false);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `SectionsPagerAdapter` is what tells the `ViewPager` which fragment goes where.  Its `getCount()` method returns '3', so the `ViewPager` has three pages.  The `getItem()` method returns the fragment you want for the page at `position`. So if you want your list view fragment to occur on the first page, you have to create that fragment in `getItem()` and return it when `position == 0`.

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ListFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SecondFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ThirdFragment();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So I added another class that has "ListFragment" however im not sure where and how to implement the listview and such.. I've added the "ListFragment" but i've named it "TheWallFragment"

Comment: I also updated my MainActivity, I placed my ArrayAdapter for my listview in there because I wasnt sure if I should put it in the ListFragment.. Im getting an error when it runs, i'm not entirely sure if the way I have it setup is even correct..